# How to change textbox's background in specific positions of the text in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-2.0

I have a text box and I want that when the user clicks on some letter of the text,the letter's background will change.
someone has any Idea of how to implement this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`SelectionBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionbackground%28VS.95%29.aspx) property

```
<TextBox Height="25" Text="Sample Text" SelectionBackground="Red"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt help me because I want to change the background of few ranges.for example if my text is "I want To Change" and I want that the background of the words "want" and "Change" to be red.do you an idea of how to implement this?

Comment: How would you go about selecting those different ranges.  You'd have to build that logic first I assume and the background color would automatically follow.